# Rounded corners google maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, infowindow

How can I make an InfoWindow in google maps that has rounded corners? It tried using InfoBubble but it didn't work in IE, and also didn't work well with anchors. Does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: What version of IE did it not work in?

Comment: It worked the same in all versions of IE. Scroll bars that are unnecessary were showing, close button was outside of the bubble...